# Searchview listener not working on text change

Tags: java, android, listener, searchview

[image: home screen]

This is the home screen to an application Im building, I have a list of cardviews based on a json which displays some content. What Im trying to to do is when a user clicks on the first card with the magnifying glass, I wish to start a search using the searchview however when I click on that card it simply initialises the search view attributes but fails to trigger the listener on text change. I have created a filter class which should go through the list but not having any luck. I have commented out the list adapter and put in a log statement but this code is never reached.

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView searchView;

    private static final String TAG = "HomeScreen";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        //tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Search"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        final DreamsFragmentAdapter adapter = new DreamsFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Log.v(TAG,"position: "+tab.getPosition());
                if(tab.getPosition()==0){

                }
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void SearchButton(View view){
        Log.v(TAG,"search card pressed");
        setupSearchView();

        this.onSearchRequested();
    }

    public void openGallery(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    }

    public void startService(View view){
       startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DREAM_SETTINGS),0);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        return false;
    }

    private void setupSearchView(){
        Log.v(TAG,"searchViewCreated");

        SearchManager searchManager= (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        if(searchManager !=null){
            List<SearchableInfo> searchables = searchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();

            SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
            for (SearchableInfo inf : searchables) {
                if (inf.getSuggestAuthority() != null
                        && inf.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("applications")) {
                    info = inf;
                }
            }

            searchView = new SearchView(this);

            searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            //Search Results activity
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if(newText.length() > 0){
                    Log.v(TAG,"Text box changed");
                    //ListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout of Tab 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:visibility="gone"
    android:onClick="SearchButton"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageSearchView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/action_search_black"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textArticle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textTitle"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard" />




    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Search view]

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a Searchable Configuration:** The first thing you need is an `XML` file called the searchable configuration. This file is traditionally named `searchable.xml` and must be saved in the `res/xml/` project directory.

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

**2. Declaring a searchable activity:** In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, declare the `HomeScreen` activity to accept the `ACTION_SEARCH` intent, in an `<intent-filter>` element and specify the `searchable configuration` to use, in a `<meta-data>` element.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application ... >
    <activity android:name=".HomeScreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>

    ................
    .......................
</application>
```

Comment: I have already specified this in my android manifest as well as created the searchable XML and I still don't understand why the search listener is not being initiated.

Answer (score 0):

User error I was using both search dialogue and searchwidget. Once I clicked on the search button is was setting of search dialogue with the following method

```
this.onSearchRequested();
```

However my implementation was for a search view, the listener was connected to the searchview and not the search dialogue.